# How can I target first iframe to fifth iframe using css?

Tags: html, css

I am working on css, for me code is getting dynamically so I putting a screen shot for your reference[image]

Now can you please tell me how to apply display block form first iframe, to fifth iframe using nth child, I tried it but it's not working.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Paste the code into the question please.

Comment: HI @Someone_who_likes_SE code is coming dynamically, I don't have code in my html that's why I post image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```css
#wrapper iframe:nth-child(-n+5) {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi @h-sifat, I tried your code it's not working

Comment: @Vamsi try the updated code. Hope it works

Comment: Hi @h-sifat, I tried the updated code it's not working.

Comment: Sorry about that, then I don't know how to do it. Update the question then and show us your code so that we can try it ourselves!

Comment: Hi @h-sifat, I just modified your answer that is the solution to my question. #wrapper iframe:nth-child(-n+7) {
  display: none;
}  ---> this is working fine thank you.

Comment: Hi @h-sifat, can you please answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126877/how-to-block-unnecessary-iframes-in-my-code-using-css

Answer (score 1):

Then keep the first 5 iframe in a div with class name="display-block" , then in CSS:

```
.display-block iframe{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id 'display-block' from 1st to 5th iframe and then add css-

```
#display-block{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tamim, for me code is getting dynamically so I can't give.