# How to block unnecessary iframes in my code using css?

Tags: css

I am working on html and Css, for code is getting dynamically so I cannot post the code that's why I am attaching a picture of code. My problem is how to remove Iframes from code using display none Css property. I need to remove first and second iframe from a parent of id='wrapper'.

[image]

If you have any questions please ping me once.

Comment: Hey @Cruse I answered a similar question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061804/how-can-i-target-first-iframe-to-fifth-iframe-using-css?noredirect=1&lq=1    . Try modifying the value after n. See the accepted solution. That might help.

Comment: Use #wrapper iframe:nth-of-type(-n+2) { display: none }

Answer (score 0):

You can edit their style with javascript.

```js
count = 0
var div = document.querySelector('#wrapper')
for (var iframe of div.children){
  if (count < 2 && iframe.tagName === "IFRAME"){
    iframe.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;')
    count ++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>This is ignored</p>
  <iframe style="display:block">Removed</iframe>
  <p>This is also ignored</p>
  <iframe style="display:block">Removed</iframe>
  <iframe style="display:block; background-color:green;"></iframe>
</div>
```

The count can be how many iframes you want to edit. `Note, only the iframes will be removed`, and `not` any other elements `before or between` the iframe because of the `second condition` in `if loop`